# Restore database dump with tool pg_restore returns "pg_restore: error: input file does not appear to be a valid archive"

Tags: postgresql, pg-restore

Im working on windows 10 with powershell, pgAdmin 4v6 and the user has no admin permissions.

When I create the dump with a command similar to this one:

```
pg_dump -h localhost -p 8083 -d database-name -U user --password --clean -Fc --no-acl --no-owner > backup_name.dump
```

I try to make the restore with this command:

```
pg_restore -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -d posgres-v  backup_name.dump
```

Im gettign this message:

```
pg_restore: error: input file does not appear to be a valid archive
```

Comment: I see -Fc, but check with "head backup_name.dump" if is not a binary file try "cat backup_name.dump | psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -d posgres-v " or try adding " --verbose --format=c " to pg_restore and upload the output.

Comment: Or try `file backup_name.dump`.

Comment: Don't use redirection on Windows with pg_dump use `-f backup_name.dump` instead of `> backup_name.dump`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name You sir, are my savior. Thank you. Could you elaborate on why the `>` operator shouldn't be used on Windows in this case?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the error was the dump file, I created a new one and could restore it just fine.